# Earphone microphone not recognized in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone

Windows 7 is not recognizing the microphone on any (tested 3 different) earphones when I plug them into my [Logitech Z-2300](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002SQ2P2) speakers.
[image]

In the Recording devices tab I have show disabled devices enabled, it's simply not showing up.

My motherboard is [Asus P8H77-M PRO](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8H77M_PRO/). The audio driver I am using is Realtek High Definition Audio ver. 6.0.1.7246.
Here is a picture from device manager:

[image]
FYI, Windows is not recognizing the earphone microphones even if I plug them directly into the computer chassis either. I had a USB gaming headset that had a perfectly functioning mic until it broke yesterday.

EDIT: I realized what this was after Bertieb's answer, plugged it into the chassis, but no reaction from the computer.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing your speakers first. Pictured is a headphone jack, which will only output, not input so a microphone won't work. What you need is a microphone/input jack; which are usually in red and have a symbol of a microphone:

[image: two audio jacks]

*(I took that photo rather quickly because I couldn't find a suitably licensed 
image, microphone jack is on the left)*

When plugging your headset into your computer, you will want to plug the two split ends into the corresponding jack.

If instead you have only one combined 3.5mm connector on your headphones which looks like:

[image: combined connector]

*(Thanks to **Imaadwhd** on [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:3.5mm.jpg) for this image)*

You will either need a combined headset input (I have no picture for this sorry), but it looks like the headphones one with a microphone attachment, commonly seen on mobile phone jacks; or a [splitter](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=3.5mm+microphone+and+speaker+splitter+male+to+female), with one female input and two male outputs. The adapter pictured is an in-flight adapter, for use on airplanes.

Comment: Good man! new problem arose though. See Edit.

Comment: Getting somewhere :) Did you check that the adapter is both oriented correctly (I don't see markings for which is which); and of a suitable type (it certainly looks like it but worth asking!) for the headset connector?

Comment: the adapter came with akg headphones. I just managed to get sound. It's from right side only and the sound quality is awfully distorted. Still no mic. (the other orientation doesn't give me anything)

Comment: ohhh. It says AKG flight on the adapter -.-

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's for using it on airplanes which is why the audio is split and the mic isn't working :) Unfortunately, that means unless you have another adapter you will have to buy one.

Comment: Alright, I'll comment with new questions if something comes up.

Comment: Why do all these earphones work on laptops but no my computer? mic and sound is perfect on my laptop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25232/discussion-between-bertieb-and-manumit).